# Take list of strings and split it based on commas into 2d list

Tags: python, list, split, readfile

So far I have the the following code:

```
def display2dlist(data):
    for i in data:               #loops through list
        lines = i.strip()       #removing leading and trailing characters
        split_lines = lines.split(", ")       #splitting lines by ','
        print(split_lines)       #prints list


with open("python.csv", "r") as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()[0:]       #reads lines from file 
#print(data)
display2dlist(data)       #calling the function display2dlist with data list as parameter
```

It reads lines from a csv file and saves each line as a list.
It outputs this:

```
['2016,London,10']
['2017,Tokyo,11']
['2018,Toronto,12']
['2018,Dubai,23']
```

How would I make it so instead of saving each line as just one big string. It splits the lines at every comma and saves multiple values. So it should look like this:

```
['2016','London','10']
['2017','Tokyo','11']
['2018','Toronto','12']
['2018','Dubai','23']
```

For example in my current code:

```
data[0][0]= '2'
data[0][1]= '0'        #it is treating it as a big string and just going letter by letter
data[0][2]= '1'
data[1][0]= '2'
data[1][1]= '0'         
data[1][2]= '1'
```

I want it so when I execute the previous code the output is:

```
data[0][0]='2016'
date[0][1]='London'
data[0][2]='10'
data[1][0]='2017'
data[1][1]='Tokyo'         
data[1][2]='11'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extra space in split method and use thos function to get nested list:

```
def get_2d(data):
    listdata = []
    for i in data:
        split_lines = i.strip().split(",") #  not ", "
        listdata.append(split_lines)
    return listdata

...

with open("python.csv", "r") as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()[0:] 
print(get_2d (data))
```

Comment: thanks but this only prints it like that. It doesn't actually save as a 2dlist.

Comment: Edited now... tell me if ok

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_data(data):  #data given as list 
    return [i.split(',') for i in data]  #if data is not in list, wrap this in []


#example:
my_data = ['2020,10,10']

split_data(my_data)

#returns
[['2020', '10', '10']]
```